# how to write the struct data into an text file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct

i have following struct array called "Forces" (1 by 565) with fields

ID            Matrix(1*1)

X             char(1*1)

Y             char(1*1)

Z             char(1*1)

Force         Matrix(1*3)

ID gives the identification number X,Y,Z gives their coordinates respectively and Force gives the Forces acting on the particular node in X,Y,Z direction.

I Need to convert this data into a text file with 8-digits for each variable in the following way

```
12345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678

FORCE   2       IDVALUE 1.0     XFORCE  YFORCE  ZFORCE
```

8-digit variable means each value will be stored with 8 spaces and when it is shorter remaining will be spaces, there is no data longer than 8-digits.

Comment: Take a look at `fprintf()`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I converted the struct into a form of Matrix now, and now going to try with fprintf().